# d3.js sorting graph by both axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently plotting a list of numbers (y-axis) against a list of titles (x-axis). Each number can correspond to multiple websites. Right now I've been using the ascending function provided by d3 to sort them. I've currently got a drop-down menu in which I can pick either number or title and each option individually sorts by the respective choice. However, I was wondering if there was a way so that I could sort alphabetically by title, and then keeping it alphabetical, also sort by number. As of now I can only do one or the other.

Example: 
My data is stored in a CSV like this:

```
"id","name"  
1,"youtube"  
1,"google"  
2,"google"  
3,"nike"  
4,"google"
```

Then I use

```
d3.csv("csvTestFile.csv", function (dataset)
```

to read in the file and I convert the id number to ints.

To sort I do the following:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.id, b.id)});
```

To sort by ID. To sort by name I do this:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name)});
```

Both of these work properly, however I would like to first sort by ID, then also sort by Name. So the axis would display (starting from the origin) 1, 2, 3, 4 up the y-axis, and google, nike, youtube down the x-axis. Right now if I try to sort it will either be 1, 2, 3, 4 up to the y-axis and youtube, google, nike down the x-axis OR google, youtube, nike down the x-axis with 1, 2, 4, 3 up the y-axis.

What I want is 1, 2, 3, 4 up the y-axis (sorted numerically) and google, nike, youtube down the x-axis (sorted alphabetically) at the same time. Given this is a scatterplot it should be something simply like rearranging the ticks on the axis but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you have? Basically you just have to modify the sorting function accordingly to what you want.

Comment: I added a lot more detail. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Christopher Chice for the edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which input values are mapped to output values for a categorical scale depends on the order in which they are given to `.domain()`. All you need to do to achieve what you want is to sort the values accordingly when you create the scale, i.e. something like

```
var scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(data.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); }))
   .range([...]);
```

Comment: That's interesting. Does that mean when I pick a different option on my drop-down menu, I should sort the data, then modify the scale?

Comment: That would be one way of doing it, yes.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't seem to be working for me but I believe it may be an issue with how I described the graph to you. Right now it looks something like this fiddle I found on here: http://jsfiddle.net/WEsUe/1/. Obviously in this example the axis are both sorted at the same time, but given the data was not inputted in sorted format, how would I go about it so that both my axis are sorted at the same time?

Comment: You simply add a call to `.sort()` to the return value of your `map` that you pass to `.domain()`.

Comment: Could you let me know what it would look like using the example? Would I be doing d.sort() instead of simply returning d.country?